# For $g, g' \in G$, show that $gA=g'A$ if and only if $gA \cap g'A$ is non empty.

Tags: group-theory

> For $g,g' \in G$, show that $gA=g'A$ if and only if $gA \cap g'A$ is non empty.

Here $A\le G$.

I have the Lemma that if $g, g'$ are in $G$ then $gH \cap g'H = \emptyset$ or $gH=g'H$ but I am not sure how to apply this to answering this proof.

It is a 5 mark past paper question.

Thanks

Comment: What are G,H and A??

Comment: g is an element in G and G is a group and A is a subgroup

Comment: Thats what I thought but I don't feel that  the proof of this lemma proves the statement I am given.

Comment: "If x in gH$\cup$g' then x=gh=g'h' for h,h' in H. Then g=g'h'h$^{-1}$ and so gH=g'h'h$^{-1}$H=g'H since h' is in H, thus h'H=H."

Comment: Are you sure it is $gH \cup g'H$? I think it should be $gH \cap g'H$. The theorem, as stated, makes little (if any) sense.

Comment: oh yes my mistake, sorry I've copied it down wrong.

Comment: Anyway: given the lemma, if $gA \cap g'A$ is non-empty, then we must have $gA=g'A$ (because either $gA \cap g'A=\emptyset$ or $gA=g'A$). Conversely, if $gA=g'A$, clearly $gA \cap g'A$ is non-empty.
PS: I guess the examiner wants you to actually prove the lemma and then use it to show the above result.

Comment: could you please explain to me how it is clear that $gA \cap g'A$ is non empty, thanks.

Comment: Since $gA=g'A$, we have $gA \cap g'A=gA(=g'A)$ and clearly $gA$ is non-empty ($A$ is a subgroup, so it has to contain at least the unit element, hence $gA$ is non-empty)!

Comment: of course, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*To summarise the comments into an answer . . .*

Due to the Lemma, if $gA\cap g'A\neq \varnothing$, then $gA=g'A$.

Conversely, if $gA=g'A$, then $gA=gA\cap g'A(=g'A)$, and $gA$ is nonempty since $A$ is a group (and so contains $e$).